# Junk values required in variable in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, string, unions

I am trying to store the two unsigned character array elements into an string variable. one of the variable will contain junk characters, when i am trying store the junk characters is not able store along with a valid value.

This is my code

```
union u_type 
{
    unsigned int IntVar;
    unsigned char Bytes[2];
} temp; 

void main(void)
{
    temp.IntVar = 39;
    printf("%c%c",temp.Bytes[1],temp.Bytes[0]);
}
```

when I am running this code `cc test.c` and `./a.out > tempfile`
Now the tempfile is containing the below contents

> `^@'`

I understood that

`temp.Bytes[1]` is `^@` and `temp.Bytes[0]` is `'`.

I want to merge two array elements into a string that should contain `^@'`. I have tried the below way.

```
printf("%c%c",temp.Bytes[1],temp.Bytes[0]);
memcpy(string, &temp.Bytes[1],1);
memcpy(string,&temp.Bytes[0],1);
printf("%s",str);
```

Now str contains only `'` But, I want to store like this `^@'` into an string variable.

Comment: You can't expect an unitialized variable to have the same value in every execution. When you run the program a second time, Bytes[0] and Bytes[1]  could have completely different values.

Comment: Also, memcpy will overwrite the contents of string when you call it the second time. If you wanted to add two chars to your string, you should do something like string[0]=Bytes[0]; string [1]=Bytes[1]

Comment: For completeness you want to show us how `str` is defined ans initialised.

Comment: The two calls to `memcpy()` copy one byte each to the exact same address.

Comment: Also, think twice, you want to receive a result made out of *three* characters (`"^@'"`) by copying *two* bytes. How should this work? Something doesn't fit here ...

Answer (score 3):

`^@` is how some C functions print a null character (`'\0'`).  But that character is also treated as the end of a string.  So it won't normally appear in the output of `printf("%s")`.  The character is *there* (all normal C strings have one at the end) but you have to do something special to print it.

Comment: well it's not there because of the second `memcpy()` that overwrites the `NUL`. If it was, `printf()` would print nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problems with your `memcpy` are 2:

1. You are always coping items to the same address: first byte of `string` variable
2. Probably the resulting string is not null-terminated. I'm writing *probably* because of I don't know how `string` is defined.

3rd thing I think you are missing something with size of `int` type:

Try this

```
union u_type
{
   unsigned int IntVar;
   unsigned char Bytes[sizeof(int)];
}temp;

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;

    temp.IntVar = 39;

    printf("Size of int: %zu\n", sizeof(int));

    for (i=1; i<sizeof(int)+1; i++)
        printf("%02X ",temp.Bytes[sizeof(int)-i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
4
00 00 00 27
```

So you should do your job using c-string standard functions: i.e. `sprintf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union u_type
{
   unsigned int IntVar;
   unsigned char Bytes[sizeof(int)];
}temp;

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    char string[(sizeof(int)*2)+1] = {0};
    uint8_t index = 0;

    temp.IntVar = 39;

    for (i=1; i<sizeof(int)+1; i++)
    {
        index += sprintf(&string[index], "%02X", temp.Bytes[sizeof(int)-i]);
    }

    printf(string);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
00000027
```

Take note that all my code is not taking care of endianness.
You can do that using a simple function, as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

union u_type
{
  unsigned int IntVar;

  unsigned char Bytes[sizeof(int)];
}temp;

bool is_big_endian ( void )
{
  unsigned int x = 1;
  char *c = (char*) &x;
  return (bool)*c;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    char string[(sizeof(int)*2)+1] = {0};
    uint8_t index = 0;

    temp.IntVar = 0x12345678;

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));

    if (is_big_endian())
    {
        for (i=1; i<sizeof(int)+1; i++)
        {
            index += sprintf(&string[index], "%02X", temp.Bytes[sizeof(int)-i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=0; i<sizeof(int); i++)
        {
            index += sprintf(&string[index], "%02X", temp.Bytes[i]);
        }
    }

    printf(string);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*Probably the resulting string is not null-terminator.*" It most likley is, even "more" then as expected, as the `^@` probably is `'\0'`! :-)

Comment: @alk I bet  :),  but maybe is `bss` or `calloc`-ated or zero -inited ;) Who knows...

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a `struct`, when you define a `union`, all of the `union members` are created at the same memory address, and will, depending on the member `type` *share* at least some portion of the same memory space allocated for the union. When you make an assignment to one of the members, its value is placed at that location in memory, using the appropriate number of bytes for the data `type` of that member.  If you make a subsequent assignment, to another member, perhaps of a different `type`, it will place the new value at the same location, possibly destroying part, or all of the previous value.  This is normal behavior for a union. You cannot trust that upon subsequent assignments, any previous assignment will still be viable.  Reading the value of a `union` member, after another member has been written to, is therefore undefined behavior in C.

Reproducing your scenario, you create a union:

```
union u_type 
{
    unsigned int IntVar;
    unsigned char Bytes[2];
} temp;
```

The uint requires 4 bytes, the array of uchar requires 2:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10111213141516171819202122232425262728293031
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

Upon making your first assignment, `temp.IntVar = 39` fills the memory with the value 39:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10111213141516171819202122232425262728293031
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|1|1|1| //decimal 39
```

In my environment, when reproducing this scenario, both members are located at memory location 0x0040AA30.  When viewing uint member, `temp.IntVar`, I see:
[image]

When I view the uchar member, `temp.Bytes`, I see:
[image]

Which is precisely equal to the value `39` when viewed in ASCII.  Because my memory viewer picks the default viewing format based on the type of member being viewed, it selected ASCII for the second image, to display uchar.  When I force it to view the memory in `long int`, it changes back to:
[image]

So it all really comes down to recognizing with what context (or what format) are you viewing the contents of the same memory location, and that context should always be interpreted while viewing *only* the latest assigned member.